# systemd-networkd match for LAN

Tags: systemd-networkd

I want **static LAN IP** addresses for my devices (an ethernet and wifi ) but in my usual week I connect to two LANs: two gateways, two IP ranges: a `10.0...` network and a `192.168..` network.

I have been keeping two sets of *.network files that I switch using a script, but I wonder if there's a configuration setting I can use.

I've looked in documentation, in particular at the `[Match]` section but that seems to be exclusively about devices.

Is there a *.network file configuration that I can use for this situation, or must I continue with my current strategy?

**NOTE: I don't want to use NetworkManager**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least on Debian 11, for wireless interfaces, you could use `SSID=` in the `[Match]` section to have the `.network` file apply only for a particular wireless network. But for wired interfaces, there does not seem to be any capability for restricting the `.network` file matching based on the network you're connected to.

Even the [documentation on `.network` files at freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html) does not have any suitable options for matching a particular wired network, and that documentation usually tracks the state of the newest version of the systemd suite.

The availability of various `[Match]` conditions can depend on the exact version of the systemd suite used in your Linux distribution, and on the build-time configuration choices made by the distribution. Use `systemctl --version` to see the version of the systemd suite and a list of selected build-time options.